# Python while loop does not exit, why?

Tags: python

The following function waits until a RackSpace server has been built. After which it returns that server object:

```
def _wait_for_server(cloud_server, server):
    while server.status != 'ACTIVE':
        sleep(30)
        s = cloud_server.servers.get(server.id)
        print '%s: %s (%s%%)' % (s.id, s.status, s.progress)

    return server
```

At lease that what it should so! Instead when server status reaches `Active` the while loop continues to run and never exits. Why is this happening?

Here is the terminal output to show the above code:

```
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (10%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (10%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (10%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (10%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (40%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (40%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (40%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (40%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (70%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: BUILD (80%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: ACTIVE (100%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: ACTIVE (100%)
7cbadf1b-1090-40d5-9437-9869ca392b5a: ACTIVE (100%)
... runs until the end of time or my laptop battery runs out
```

Comment: Because you're checking `server.status`, but updating `s` (not `server`) inside the while loop.

Comment: Dam it!!!!!!!!!!!!! Such a school boy error!

Comment: @Sputnik you should get yourself a [rubber duck](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop the variable `server` is never updated. You should add a `break` statement for get out from loop:

```
def _wait_for_server(cloud_server, server):
    while True:
        sleep(30)
        s = cloud_server.servers.get(server.id)
        print '%s: %s (%s%%)' % (s.id, s.status, s.progress)
        if s.status == 'ACTIVE':
            break

    return server
```

or update `server` instead of `s`:

```
def _wait_for_server(cloud_server, server):
    while server.status != 'ACTIVE':
        sleep(30)
        server = cloud_server.servers.get(server.id)
        print '%s: %s (%s%%)' % (server.id, server.status, server.progress)

    return server
```

Comment: In that case, why not just `while True`?

Comment: Neither of those will actually work, the first doesn't update server and the second tries to print elements from s which is never updates or defined

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the "s" and "server" variables have different values. You're retrieving s from the network, but never do anything with server.
I bet if you put

```
server = s
```

in there, it'll start working.